# displaying clicked data inside Input field

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

  $("#list > li").click(function(){
      var $val = $(this).text();
      $("#hi").attr('value',$val);
      });

});
</script>



<input type="text" id="hi" disabled="disabled" value=" " />
<ul id="list">
    <li>Mike
        <ul>
            <li>Smith</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
        <li>Gene</li>
            <li>Law</li>
</ul>
```

When ever i click on "law" or "Gene" it get displayed on input field, but when I click on "Smith" or "Mike" instead of single name, both of these names appear inside input field. But I want just single name on which I clicked. How to do that?

--thanks--

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your DOM structure is inflexible, you can use this:

```
$("#list > li").click(function(e) {

    // get me the first childNode of the target of the click event
    var $val = e.target.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    $("#hi").attr('value', $val);
});
```

[**You can try it here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/tn3Mr/)

Answer (score 3):

You could encase each menu item text in a span and detect a click on that:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $("#list span").click(function(){
      var $val = $(this).text();
      $("#hi").attr('value',$val);
      });

});

<input type="text" id="hi" disabled="disabled" value=" " />
<ul id="list">
    <li><span>Mike</span>
        <ul>
            <li><span>Smith</span></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
        <li><span>Gene</span></li>
            <li><span>Law</span></li>
</ul>
```

It picks up both names because you're selecting ALL of the text inside any `<li>` item

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WjTtN/1/)

Comment: @Coulton..So, how to select only the second level text? any idea? thanks

Comment: The simplest way would be to add a separate `class` to your second level list elements.

Comment: @Coulton.. I mean, if I need the solution without <span> ??